# Heroku Ruby On Rails Server Logs says 'Users' does not Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am following [Ruby On Rails Book Tutorial, Chapter 2, toy_app](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app)

Repository is on BitBucket, https://bitbucket.org/Marium36/toy_app/

So far, I can open the app on my local server, i.e

```
localhost:3000
```

and

```
localhost:3000/users
```

Problem arises with heroku.

Heroku app can only open

https://salty-wave-17330.herokuapp.com/

As soon as I attempt

https://salty-wave-17330.herokuapp.com/users

I get error,

> We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application
>   owner check the logs for more information.

Server logs, https://bitbucket.org/Marium36/toy_app/src/master/heroku_server_logs

The continual error message that shows is that `Users` does not exist --- but it does, I can load in my local machine, i.e. `localhost:3000/users`

Please help!!!

```
2019-06-29T11:24:46.008853+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.008752 #4]  INFO -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239] Started GET "/users" for PRIVATE_IP at 2019-06-29 11:24:46 +0000
2019-06-29T11:24:46.010267+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.010188 #4]  INFO -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239] Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
2019-06-29T11:24:46.013170+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.013098 #4]  INFO -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239]   Rendering users/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-06-29T11:24:46.055431+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.055315 #4] DEBUG -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239]   User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
2019-06-29T11:24:46.056103+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.056041 #4]  INFO -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239]   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (42.8ms)
2019-06-29T11:24:46.056339+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.056280 #4]  INFO -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 46ms (ActiveRecord: 13.4ms)
2019-06-29T11:24:46.057108+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.057045 #4] FATAL -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239]
2019-06-29T11:24:46.063287+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-06-29T11:24:46.057141 #4] FATAL -- : [5d839ee1-e92f-46d7-81d0-9fd508157239] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

Comment: Why is there a negative vote? I explained the question as thoroughly as possible and provided links to code repositories and logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR` means you haven't created the table. You need to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` so that the tables are added to your `Heroku Postgres`.