# Scaffolding issue in toy_app

Tags: railstutorial.org

I am working through the rails tutorial online and I've hit a snag.
I worked through the Learn Enough Rails to Be Dangerous course on my native machine (macOS Mojave) and have rails 5.1.6 installed with rbenv. I had no issues working through the Rails Tutorial until lesson 2.2. I made it all the way through the $ rails db:migrate then $ rails server commands without issue but when attempting to load my web app with "the slash" + /users, I get this error:
"The page you are looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."
The normal slash page still brings up "hello, world!" but none of the pages will load with the new files (/users, /users/1, /users/new, etc.).

I've tried deleting the application and the related repos (BitBucket, Heroku) and starting new from the beginning of lesson 2 and I still have the same problem.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I googled the error message I found in `$ heroku logs`
and found this:

[Heroku Ruby On Rails Server Logs says 'Users' does not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817347/heroku-ruby-on-rails-server-logs-says-users-does-not-exist)

which led me to the command: `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`
which solved the problem--the /users page et al are now accessable.